# Cannot create a C++ project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, c++

I am using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version 2018-12 (4.10.0) and have installed CDT (I verified this by going to installation details).

However, when I go to

> File -> New -> Project -> C++ Project

the project types are missing, and I am not able to create a new C++ project.
How can I fix this?